# calling method with Rest Template Builder

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I created this rest template with the rest template builder and set connection and read timeouts. I need to call this rest template from other methods in the program, but am unsure how to do so. please help, thanks in advance!

```
//create rest template with rest template builder and set connection and read timeouts        @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {



    return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectTimeout))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeout))
            .build();
}

// this is an example method that calls rest template, unsure what goes in the parameter section
@Bean
public example example() {
    return new restTemplate(what goes here)
    );
}
```

Comment: I think maybe you want a [RestTemplateCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateCustomizer.html).  Look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-resttemplate.html), [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder) or [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/resttemplate-builder/)

Comment: So the application I have this rest template running on calls this rest template in various parts of the repo. But before I integrated the rest template builder, the various methods of the repo would just call the default rest template, restTemplate( ). So now that I have the rest template builder integrated, that takes a parameter. How do I call the rest template now that it’s being created with the rest temple builder? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`RestTemplateBuilder` is a bean provided by Spring boot. You can inject that into any of your Spring bean classes.

Then you just want to configure your `restTemplate` at the creation of your Spring bean class and store it as a field. You can do something like below (This is not the one and only way).

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
public class MyExampleRestClientConfiguration {
    private final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public MyExampleRestClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return restTemplateBuilder
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectTimeout))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeout))
        .build();
    }
}
```

Now in Some other spring bean class, you can simply wire the `restTemplate` bean and re-use.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class MyExampleRestClient {
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public MyExampleRestClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
      this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  //Now You can call restTemplate in any method
}
```

You may refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder) for more.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am a little confused how to implement this, can you explain a little more?

Comment: I am unable to do the declaration of restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder since restTemplate is being declared as final. Also, I am not understanding still when calling the rest template, if a value goes in the parameter section

Comment: So I am declaring the final rest template inside the main class of the java file I am working in, and then I have Autowired just above the rest template that was specified above by @SupunWijerathne. when i do use that, I am unsure what would be the return value from that method. When the rest template is created do i call the rest template just by using the value of the name of the function?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the rest template being called in different areas of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code works, but oddly after my timeouts are set, I am testing to see if the application will generate a connection time out but am successful. The application is still running normally. Any ideas why the connection is not timing out? I had set connection time out to 1 second.

Comment: @DaveMichaels first I guess this timeout problem should go as a separate question, since your original question is different and its already solved. Then I have to have a proper understanding about your testing strategy and also good to have a look at your actual code now.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created your customised RestTemplate, you may autowire it any class where you want to call it and use the one. if you more than 1 RestTemplates you can use @Qualifier above RestTemplate Bean and use the same in the calling class.